# Creating custom stream in nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to add ping results (`isAlive`) to the stream below so that later I can pipe to http response but I received the following error

```
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

I don't understand what it means and would be grateful for any help afforded to me?

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var s = new Readable;
var ping = require('ping');

var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        //console.log(msg);
        s.push(msg)
    });
});
//s.push(null) ;
//s.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var s = new Readable();
var ping = require('ping');

s.on('error', function(err){
  console.error(err)
})

var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        //console.log(msg);
        s.push(msg);
    })
});
```

You were missing the `()` on `var s = new Readable`**`()`**

By adding the `error` listener to your reader, you'll see that the tool you're using is throwing the following error: `Error: not implemented`

Sorry, I thought I had sent this earlier. Fortunately stack saves unsubmitted posts.